# Bit manipulation on large integers out of 'int' range

Tags: c#, int, bit-manipulation, 32-bit, uint32

Ok, so let's start with a 32 bit integer:

```
int big = 536855551; // 00011111111111111100001111111111
```

Now, I want to set the last 10 bits to within this integer:

```
int little = 69; // 0001101001
```

So, my approach was this:

```
big = (big & 4294966272) & (little)
```

where `4294966272` is the first 22 bits, or `11111111111111111111110000000000`.

But of course this isn't supported because `4294966272` is outside of the `int` range of `0x7FFFFFFF`. Also, this isn't going to be my only operation. I also need to be able to set bits 11 through 14. My approach for that (with the same problem) was:

```
big = (big & 4294951935) | (little << 10)
```

---

So with the explanation out of the way, here is what I'm doing as alternative's for the above:

```
1: ((big >> 10) << 10) | (little)
2: (big & 1023) | ((big >> 14) << 14) | (little << 10)
```

---

I don't feel like my alternative's are the best, efficient way I could go. Is there any better ways to do this?

Sidenote: If C# supported binary literals, `'0b'`, this would be a lot prettier.

Thanks.

Comment: use BigInteger   .....?

Comment: @MitchWheat That never occurred to me... Can you show me an example (preferably as an answer so if it works I can accept it) that would reflect my examples above?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger_operators(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Side note: for public source please use hex notation or explicit bit shifts (1<<10) for numbers in bit manipulation. I don't know anyone who is able to convert 4294966272 to bits in they head when `0xFFFFFC00` can be read by most programmers easily.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I find binary a lot easier to read. Especially when my focus is setting specific bits. So no, I will not use hex representations when my main focus is bits.

Comment: @CoreyIles I think, what Alexei means is not the way to use binary representation as in in your comment (like this: `int little = 69; // 0001101001`, which is good). But when you write it as mask: (`4294966272` is harder to see than `0xFFFFFC00`). In the second rep (`0xFFFFFC00`) people can immediately see that the last 10 bits are zero. But of course when you put as comment, it is still good to show its binary representation as you did: `11111111 11111111 11111100 00000000` (and you could put space per 8 bits too)

Comment: @lan point taken. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`4294966272` should actually be `-1024`, which is represented as `11111111111111111111110000000000`.

For example:

```
int big = 536855551; 
int little = 69;
var thing = Convert.ToInt32("11111111111111111111110000000000", 2);
var res = (big & thing) & (little);
```

Though, the result will always be 0

```
00011111111111111100001111111111
&
00000000000000000000000001101001
&
11111111111111111111110000000000
```

Comment: I like this because I can define the masks as constants and it looks nice. And it works exactly like my approach but with names.

Answer (score 2):

Bit shift is usually faster compared to bit-shift + mask (that is, &). I have a [test case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34849753/get-specific-bit-from-uint32/34849792#34849792) for it.

You should go with your first alternative.

```
1: ((big >> 10) << 10) | (little)
```

Just beware of [a little difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499647/shifting-the-sign-bit-in-net) between unsigned and signed `int` when it comes to bit-shifting.

Alternatively, you could define `big` and `little` as unsigned. Use `uint` instead of `int`.

Comment: This is an acceptable answer, but Rob's is prettier if I define the masks as constants. Speed does matter a lot, but this is nothing significant. It work's just like I tried to in my approach but with names.